# My CodeIgniter project does not work in server

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __costruct(){
        parent::__costruct();

        $login = $this->session->userdata('login');
        if(!empty($login)){

        if($login!='valid'){

            } else {
                redirect('login/index');
            }       
        } else{
            redirect('login/index');
        }


    }

    protected $template  = array();


    public function layout($arg = array()) {
        $this->template['header']       = $this->load->view('theme/header_theme', $arg, true);
        $this->template['header_menu']     = $this->load->view('theme/header_menu_theme', $arg, true);
        $this->template['sidebar']          = $this->load->view('theme/sidebar_theme',$arg, true);
        $this->template['content']      = $this->load->view($this->content, $arg, true);
        $this->template['footer']           = $this->load->view('theme/footer_theme',$arg, true);

        $this->load->view('theme/index_theme', $this->template);
    }
```

Comment: Your question does not actually contain a written question. "Does not work" is not a question, neither is "How do I get it to work?" Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you setting poor fish on fire? What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: @deceze: I have a goldfish flamethrower here and I'm not afraid to use it.

Comment: @halfer Is that a goldfish that throws flames? Or something which throws flaming goldfish?! Either way: awesome!

Comment: @deceze: I think it'll have to be the first one, otherwise I'll have the [RSPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society_for_the_Prevention_of_Cruelty_to_Animals) after me! `:=O`

Comment: I have an app that does not work. `<?php ?>`

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading it right, and if that is the code used, the mistake is a simple spelling mistake.

```
function __costruct(){
        parent::__costruct();
```

should have been

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
```

Anyways, it is always better to use the server in development mode to check the same!!!